# Trig substitution in calculating integral

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$
\int \sin^5x \cos x\,dx
$$

I used a trig substitution using $\sin$ and $\cos$, while I got two different answers, can someone explain any possible reason for the inconsistency? I got:
$$
\frac{1}{6}\sin^6x
$$
and
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2x - \frac{1}{6}\cos^6x -\frac{1}{2}\cos^4x
$$

Comment: is it $$\sin(x)^5$$ or $$\sin(x^5)$$?

Comment: How did you get those answers?

Comment: You can check your answer by computing the derivative and verifying that it's the same as the integrand. You might also ask whether or not your two answers are in fact different, as sometimes one writes the same thing in different ways.

Comment: @MathLover More precisely, at least one of the solutions is not correct.

Comment: It's (sinx)^5. The first one

Comment: Are you sure these two answers don't agree?

Comment: They are equal to each other actually; I didn't know how to get them agree so I posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is
$$\frac16\sin^6x+C.$$
But that equals
$$\frac16(1-\cos^2x)^3+C=-\frac12\cos^2x+\frac12\cos^4x-\frac16\cos^6x+C'$$
which I suspect is what you intended to write,

Comment: yea, exactly. It should be a - before 1/6. I'll edit my original post.